# Difference between mb_substr and substr

Tags: php, string, multibyte

Will it make any difference or impact on my result, if I use `substr()` instead of `mb_substr()` function?

As my server does not have support for mb_ functions, I have to replace it with `substr()`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will impact your script if you work with multi-byte text that you substring from. If this is the case, I higly recommend enabling mb_* functions in your php.ini or do this `ini_set("mbstring.func_overload", 2);`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload
> This setting can only be changed from the php.ini file.

Comment: This has been deprecated.

Answer (score 90):

If you have utf-8 encoding use mb_substr

Example :

```
echo substr("hi mémé", 0 , 5); // will print hi m�
echo mb_substr("hi mémé", 0 , 5); // will print hi mé
```

Comment: This one actually does answer the question while the accepted answer doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

> string [substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

> string [mb_substr ( string $str , int $start [, int $length [, string
>   $encoding ]] )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of characters. Position is counted from the beginning of str. First character's position is 0. Second character position is 1, and so on.

Comment: Note that the php.ini setting mbstring.func_overload can affect this difference, so that substr actually uses the mb_substr code

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone : this is also the case with substr().. Position is counted from the beginning of str. First character's position is 0. Second character position is 1