# Want to trim word in worpress which is in Chinese letter

Tags: wordpress

I have used `wp_trim_words` for get words in Wordpress paragraph. The paragraph is in Chinese letter. I want to get 10 words from the wordpress paragraph. But it is showing more work. i think.If it actual 10 words, then i want to take 30 character, So i used `substr()` for this. This is also return a different symbol in this.

I have used this for getting 10 words

```
wp_trim_words( get_the_content($postlist->post->ID), 10 )
```

It is showing like this

[image: The picture after use wp_trim_wors]
After this i have tried also this

$result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);

I got this after use substr()
[image: this is after substr]

Comment: you need to save the file in utf8 format.

Comment: Do you mean in the DB ?

Comment: No. your functions.php file

Comment: Can you say how to save a file in utf8 format ?

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: I am using sublime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176997/discussion-between-ranjit-and-george).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mb_substr` instead of `substr`.

```
mb_substr( get_the_content($postlist->post->ID), 0, 10, "utf-8" );
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really work. Can you explain this. I will give a up vote this answer.

Comment: `multi-byte text` please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120732/difference-between-mb-substr-and-substr

Comment: I gave the answer bellow. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the answer by @George and i got the explanation like this from google. I think it will help a lot

It will impact your script if you work with multi-byte text that you substring from. If this is the case, I higly recommend enabling mb_* functions in your php.ini or do this ini_set("mbstring.func_overload", 2);

Please follow the link [Difference between mb_substr and substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120732/difference-between-mb-substr-and-substr)